# Xdebug don't break if file name have some upper case letters

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, breakpoints, phalcon

I use PHP, framework Phalcon, xdebug and IDE NetBeans.

I noticed that XDebug don't stop on breakpoint if file name have some upper case letters.

**For example:** If I created controller with file name `TestController.php` works good, but if I put name `TesTController.php` xdebug don't stop in any breakpoints this file.

In both case controller was loaded correct.

**UPADTE**

from xdebug_remote.log:

filename: **TesthelloController.php**

This breakpoint working

```
<- breakpoint_set -i 1383 -t line -s enabled -f file:///var/www/project/app/controllers/TesthelloController.php -n 25
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="1383" state="enabled" id="19950012"></response>
```

After change file name to **TestHelloController.php** breakpoint don't working

```
<- breakpoint_set -i 1550 -t line -s enabled -f file:///var/www/project/app/controllers/TestHelloController.php -n 25
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="1550" state="enabled" id="19250022"></response>
```

Comment: Why do you type the classname wrong in the first place. OK, php ignores cases when accessing a class (for whatever reason), but why do you type it wrong? And keep in mind xdebug != php, so if xdebug is case sensitive, you have to type it always right.

Comment: If your file system is case-sensitive .. then yes, it's normal/expected. You can enable xdebug log and see what files it will operate with (what file names appear in communication with NetBeans).

Comment: Okay I added information from the xdebug_remoge.log. Maybe the main reason is why that I use netbeans on windows but server is on Debian in virtual machine?

Comment: Your Debian OS is using case-sensitive file system .. so it's expected behaviour as `TestHelloController.php` and `TesthelloController.php` would be 2 different files.

Comment: Okay I understand, but breakpoint have correct path with case sensitive